# Creating User HTML Control

Tags: c#

I want to create a Custom Html Control.

In the ASPX :

```
<custom:Message runat="server" ID="" 
                Type="" // { "Tip", "Note", "Important", "Warning" , "Caution" }
                Label=""
                Text=""
                Visible="" />
```

The Html generated :

```html
<div class="fixedClass customClass">
<span class="label">caution</span><hr>
<blockquote>
    <p>
        <strong>Important:</strong> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ipsum lectus, cursus id rutrum vel
        , feugiat eget leo. <strong>Cras suscipit urna vel</strong> nibh placerat vestibulum. 
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Attribute: 
Type is for the customClass of the main div.
Label is the text in the `<span class="label">`.
Text is the text in the `<p>` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET User Controls for this. It's a very common, well-used feature of ASP.NET Forms. I'm surprised your research didn't turn it up already :-)

Anyway, you can create a new User Control when you go to "Add New Item" in Visual Studio. Choose "Web User Control" from the list of templates. This will create a file with a .ascx extension - this is your user control. In it you can add any HTML markup you want, javascript, and other .NET controls (and even other user controls). It also has code-behind which can respond to events etc. in the same way as a full page.

Once that's created and included in your project, you can use in your main aspx pages. This is in two parts - first add a directive to register the control, and then you can add a tag to use the control in the same way as the built-in controls.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="myControl" Src="~/Controls/myControl.ascx" %>
...
<uc:myControl id="ctrl1" runat="server"/>
```

If you want to have attributes on the control (e.g. "Label" and "Text" as you discussed, define public properties in the code-behind of the control:

```
public string Label { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Then obviously somewhere in the code behind you can use these values to populate the UI or whatever.

To use them in the markup:

```
<uc:myControl id="ctrl1" runat="server" Label="TestLabel" Text="TestText" />
```

Alternatively you can populate them from the code-behind of the page where you're using the control, just like any public property of an object.

More info can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3k2fyw.aspx (how to create user controls)
and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx (how to include them in your page)

Comment: I have search but in the wrong direction. Searching for 'custom control' instead of 'User Control' . Thx for the quick answer. Im RTFM right now. You will have your well deserved Green tick once I've finish the control.

Comment: May i update my question with my version of the User control. Because i don't know why but i don't find it "efficient"

Comment: in what sense efficient? it's slow to execute, or you don't think it helps your code structure?

Comment: Its not slow , It works. I m not really good in English. So i should have say I don't find it sexy. Because for exemple, I Set the label properties in the 'set' of my `public string Text { get; set; }`

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you are getting at. Perhaps you should create a new question with all the details of what you find inefficient. I and others can then review and see if there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Well it's ok, i am more confortable with my 'not-sexy' code, than with asking for a review for this simple dummy code.

Comment: IMHO if you feel like creating "sexier" code, I would drop ASP.NET Forms entirely and adopt MVC :-). I did it a year ago and it's a revelation. Forms distorts the web in so many ways and makes things more difficult than they should be. MVC is a lot easier to work with. P.S. The equivalent of the User Control in MVC terms is either a Partial View or a HTML Helper, depending on the exact requirements.

Comment: Do you  have any good mvc tutorial to advice me ? Like the symphony Jobeet?

Comment: Is it possible to do both ? because an old dev have already done 50+pages in asp.net

Comment: There are hundreds of good tutorials including ones made by Microsoft, they are quite good. It's easy to find them. But no you can't really mix MVC and forms inside the same solution, unless you want two UIs that you deploy separately. Their lifecycles and conventions are fundamentally different. Maybe one to try next time you need to create a new UI